# HTML-Table in powershell output

Tags: html, css, powershell, html-table

I have a problem with my html output. My code with a loop that sequentially takes the IP address from the list and makes the following table. I need another tables from data of another switches.

[image]

My problem is that I do not know exactly how to repeat only the table + its title and then write and release it in one html file.

This is my HTML code for the table I'm calling the variable.

```
$Table = @" 
<table 
width: 912px;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-width: 2px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: grey;
font: 14pt Calibri;
color: black;
margin-bottom: 10px;
text-align: center;>

<h2>Switch 1</h2>
<div class=subtitle>
THIS is table from switch 1
</div>

<tbody>
<tr>   
<th
height="18" width="90"; 
<td>
Adresa IP</span>
     </td>
     </th>

<th
height="18" width="90"; 
<td>
Počet portů</span>
     </td>
     </th>

<th
height="18" width="90"; 
<td>
Obsazené porty</span>
     </td>
     </th>

<th
height="18" width="90"; 
<td>
Volné porty</span>
     </td>
     </th>

<th
height="18" width="440"; 
<td>
Neaktivní porty</span>
     </td>
     </th>
</tr>

     <tr>
     <td 
height="18" width="90";
border-bottom-width: 2px; 
border-bottom-style: inset;">
    <span 
style="color: black; 
font-family: Calibri; 
font-size: 11pt; ">
$_</span>
     </td>

     <td 
height="18" width="90"; 
border-bottom-width: 2px; 
border-bottom-style: inset;">
    <span 
style="color:black; 
font-family: Calibri; 
font-size: 12pt; ">
$PocetPortu</span>
      </td>

      <td 
height="18" width="90"; 
border-bottom-width: 2px; 
border-bottom-style: inset;">
    <span 
style="color:black; 
font-family: Calibri; 
font-size: 11pt; ">
$OP
</span>
      </td>

      <td 
height="18" width="90"; 
border-bottom-width: 2px; 
border-bottom-style: inset;">
     <span 
style="color:black; 
font-family: Calibri; 
font-size: 11pt; ">
$PP</span>
     </td>

     <td 
height="18" width="440"; 
border-bottom-width: 2px; 
border-bottom-style: inset;">
     <span 
style="color:black; 
font-family: Calibri; 
font-size: 11pt; ">
$vypis</span>
     </td>
</tbody>
</table>
"@
```

Only the one, the last table, always appears on the output page, and I have the HTML code captured in the loop where I get the values into the variables.

The command is called using:

```
$html | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Top_Head, $Style -Body $Table  -PostContent $Post_text | Out-File C:\test\test.html

Invoke-Expression C:\test\test.html
```

Thank You.

Comment: Is maybe `Out-File -Append` what you need?

Comment: Your HTML code has multiple issues with missing tags, invalid properties and general code issues - you will need to fix these for it to display correctly!

Comment: This is only part of the code what I need to repeat. The remaining tags are, of course, in my code. I need only repeat a table with dynamically changing values and is therefore not dependent on any other style of writing.

Answer (score 2):

Output your data to an object and then use `ConvertTo-Html` to do the heavy lifting and create the html for the table.

This won't allow you to use the inline css you already have, but all the style information can be moved to the a single location with `<style></style>`

I don't know how you're getting the switch information, so I've hardcoded values to use as example values:

```
# array containing a value for input into code to get switch information
$switches = '192.168.7.1','10.0.7.1'

foreach ($switch in $switches) {

    # your code to get switch information
    # output values from this code go in object below
    # example values used as we don't have this code

    $switch_info = [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Adresa IP' = $switch
        'Počet portů' = '48'
        'Obsazené porty' = '38'
        'Volné porty' = '10'
        'Neaktivní porty' = '7 8 13 14'
    }

    $table_title = "<div class=subtitle>This is table from switch $($switches.IndexOf($switch) + 1)</div>"
    $table_html = $switch_info | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment | Out-String

    $tables += $table_title
    $tables += $table_html
}

$Style = @'
<style>
table{
width: 912px;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-width: 2px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: grey;
font: 14pt Calibri;
color: black;
margin-bottom: 10px;
text-align: center;
}
th {
    background-color: #0000ff;
    color: white;
}
</style>
'@

$Top_Head = '<div>TopHead</div>'
$Post_text = '<div>PostText</div>'

ConvertTo-Html -Head $Top_Head,$Style -Body '<h2>Switch Information</h2>',$tables -PostContent $Post_text | Out-File C:\test\test.html
```

---

EDIT: Just seen your variable names, you can likely use these like so:

```
    $switch_info = [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Adresa IP' = $switch
        'Počet portů' = $PocetPortu
        'Obsazené porty' = $OP
        'Volné porty' = $PP
        'Neaktivní porty' = $vypis
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but this is hard to get another table. I need it to go dynamically because the number of switches is changing. Do you understand me?

Comment: See update - now uses a foreach loop to go through the switches.

Comment: Now I generate additional tables, but with each launch, their number increases and they are the same. This `$tables += $table_title, $tables += $table_html` is like an increment.

Comment: You're asking me to fault find your code without showing it to me, this isn't possible.